# Valgrind : Invalid read of size 1

Tags: c, valgrind

I have the following code and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error from valgrind
(for context I'm trying to copy a text from file into a string variable)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *fp;
  int f_size;
  char *string;

  fp = fopen("./src/input.txt", "rw+");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
  }

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  f_size = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

  string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * f_size);
  fread(string, sizeof(char), f_size, fp);
  printf("\n%s\n", string);
  
  free(string);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
} /* main */
```

I get the following error by the printf seems like

```
==19085== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19085== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19085== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19085== Command: ./build/find_word
==19085== 

==19085== Invalid read of size 1
==19085==    at 0x483EF54: strlen (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19085==    by 0x48CEE94: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1688)
==19085==    by 0x48B7EBE: printf (printf.c:33)
==19085==    by 0x10958C: main (main.c:44)
==19085==  Address 0x4a4932e is 0 bytes after a block of size 142 alloc'd
==19085==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19085==    by 0x109555: main (main.c:42)
==19085== 
text from file
==19085== 
==19085== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19085==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19085==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 5,734 bytes allocated
==19085== 
==19085== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19085== 
==19085== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==19085== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer you allocated is large enough to hold the characters read from the file, but nothing else.  Assuming the file contains only text, that means `string` is not actually a string because there is no terminating null byte.  So when you pass it to `printf`, it reads past the end of the allocated memory, which is what valgrind is telling you.

You need to add 1 to the amount of memory allocated and manually write a 0 to that last byte after filling the buffer to have a proper string.

```
string = malloc(sizeof(char) * f_size + 1);
fread(string, sizeof(char), f_size, fp);
string[f_size] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I forgot the null terminating byte.

Answer (score 3):

You need one extra byte to store null character.

```
string = malloc(sizeof(char) * f_size + 1);
```

After read terminate the array with null character as below. You could use return value of `fread` to terminate the string.

```
size_t ret = fread(string, sizeof(char), f_size, fp);
if (ret != -1) {
   string[ret] = 0;
} else {
   //Error
}
```